# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - Mavericks (Yosemite, El Capitan...)

Tags: c++, macos, linker, static-libraries, 32bit-64bit

**EDIT :**

**If you fall on this post, you may want to jump directly to the answer**

---

I sent a post about my confusion earlier this morning

[machine type (C++ librairies) : i386 vs x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012436/machine-type-c-librairies-i386-vs-x86-64)

But I guess I did a mistake by being not precise. So I decided to give an example of situations I face and that I can not understand.

**STEP 1**

I build a library on machine A, a 2 years old mac with OS x 10.7.5 (that I guess is 64 bits; my guess being based on the commands you will see below in Additional Info) using the following files.

A header SimpleClass.hpp:

```
#ifndef SIMPLECLASS_HPP
#define SIMPLECLASS_HPP

class SimpleClass
{
public:
  SimpleClass();
  SimpleClass(const SimpleClass& orig);
  virtual ~SimpleClass();
private:

} ;

#endif  /* SIMPLECLASS_HPP */
```

A source file SimpleClass.cpp:

```
#include "SimpleClass.h"
#include <iostream>

SimpleClass::SimpleClass()
{
  std::cout << "A new instance of Simple Class was created" << std::endl;
}

SimpleClass::SimpleClass(const SimpleClass& orig)
{
}

SimpleClass::~SimpleClass()
{
}
```

I create the library using

```
~/cpp_test$ clang++ -c -o SC.o -I SimpleClass.hpp SimpleClass.cpp

~/cpp_test$ ar rcs libtest_sc.a SC.o
```

Additional info on machine A:

```
~/cpp_test$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
~/cpp_test$ uname -m
x86_64
~/cpp_test$ uname -p
i386
~/cpp_test$ lipo -info libtest_sc.a 
input file libtest_sc.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libtest_sc.a is architecture: x86_64
```

**STEP 2**

I copy SimpleClass.hpp as well as the library to another machine B that is a 5 years old mac with osx 10.6.7 that I believe is 32 bits. And I write the following hello file to test the library

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleClass.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  SimpleClass testObj;
  return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, no problems at linking with the library and I get.

```
[~/Downloads/Gmail-9]$ g++ -o hello -L. -ltest_sc hello.cpp
[~/Downloads/Gmail-9]$ ./hello
Hello World!
A new instance of Simple Class was created
```

Additional info on Machine B:

```
[~/Downloads/Gmail-9]$ uname -m
i386
[~/Downloads/Gmail-9]$ uname -p
i386
[~/Downloads/Gmail-9]$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**STEP 3**

I copy the same library again with the same header and hello file on Machine C that is a new mac with 10.9.2 that I believe is 64 bits.

Surprisingly I have linking problems

```
MacBook-Pro:testcpp$ g++ -o hello -L. -ltest_sc hello.cpp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      SimpleClass::SimpleClass() in libtest_sc.a(SC.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libtest_sc.a(SC.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libtest_sc.a(SC.o)
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      SimpleClass::SimpleClass() in libtest_sc.a(SC.o)
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:  
      SimpleClass::SimpleClass() in libtest_sc.a(SC.o)
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      SimpleClass::SimpleClass() in libtest_sc.a(SC.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Additional Info on Machine C

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix

MacBook-Pro:testcpp$ uname -m
x86_64
MacBook-Pro:testcpp$ uname -p
i386
```

I would have expected the linking problem with machine B that is 32bits and not with machine C that is 64bits but I got the opposite. Can anyone please explain what I am missing here?

**EDIT (STEP 4)**

On machine C, when I add to the `g++` command the option `-stdlib=libstdc++`, the "undefined symbols" error disappear and the executable is running correctly. Running g++ with the option -v allowed me to notice the default `stdlib` was `libc++`and not `libstdc++`. So it seems that although the machine A and machine C are both 64 bits they don't use the same `stdlib` by default which caused the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`.

Comment: Run `file` on your object files.  You'll see what's up in short order.

Comment: Try `g++ -o hello hello.cpp -L. -ltest_sc` (different order of arguments). Also try running `file` and/or `lipo -info` on files right before you use them, not before you copy them to some place.

Comment: @CarlNorum thanks for your time.
    `file libtest_sc.a 
    libtest_sc.a: current ar archive random library`

    `file file SC.o 
    SC.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64`

I am not sure how I am supposed to use this information. I can understand that my object file is 64 bits. nothing new though...

Comment: @n.m. thanks for your time. I tried this order as well as others, and I still got the same result. Alos using `lipo -info` on the library returns the same thing on the 3 machines.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All the issues I had, that were giving

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`

were due to the fact that some libraries were compiled with **libstdc++** and could not be used for code that is compiled/linked with **libc++**

libc++ is in fact the default new library used by clang since **Mavericks**, however it is possible to compile with the same clang (no need to install an old gcc) with the classical  libstdc++ by using the option

`-stdlib=libstdc++`

---

For those who use Boost it is also possible to have boost libraries on mavericks that are compiled/linked with libstdc++ by downloading the source and using (when compiling it) instead of the classical

`./b2`

the following

`./b2 cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++"`

---

For those using Cmake, you may want to add in the adequate cmake file something similar to:

`find_library (LIBSTDCXX NAMES stdc++)`

and

`add_compile_options(-stdlib=libstdc++)`

and

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBSTDCXX} ${YOUR_OTHER_LIBRARIES))`

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, I'm using an open source library. I used the library on linux and i have no problems. Now I'm trying to use this library on mac but I get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` that is pointing to call to one of the classes functions. Any tips? Where should I include the -stdlib=libstdc++?

Comment: Specifically, it is at the "make" step.

The command "make -stdlib=libstdc++" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am sort of lazy and not going to read this, so feel free to vote down...

I think you are trying build a fat 32/64 bit library...

you have a couple of ways to do this, one if to build explicitly with 32-bit and explicitly with 64-bit... then use `lipo` to combine them.

consider nominal C++ code is stored in main.cpp

then:

```
grady$ clang++ main.cpp -m64 -o64.out
grady$ file 64.out 
64.out: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
grady$ clang++ main.cpp -m32 -o32.out
grady$ file 32.out 
32.out: Mach-O executable i386
grady$ lipo -arch i386 32.out -arch x86_64 64.out -create -output fat.out
grady$ file fat.out
fat.out: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
fat.out (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
fat.out (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

or you can generally use some shortcuts with apple tools:

```
grady$ clang++ main.cpp -arch i386 -arch x86_64  -ofat2.out
grady$ file fat2.out 
fat2.out: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
fat2.out (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
fat2.out (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I should not but I will upvote this just because you are one of the few who tried for now to answer my question (although you were not able to read the question lol). I learned something from your answer that I didn't know. However it has nothing to do with my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: Nah, you shouldn't. I understand that not all people have enough time to read my "salade Niçoise" :P

Comment: I think the simplest explanation is that the first compilation and the second compilation are both 32-bit only

Comment: actually that doesn't fit

Comment: maybe libstdC++ vs libC++ issue?

Comment: I don't know if you read my last edit, but yes, that seems to be the explanation for what is happening on machine C